# Variable not defined within vue function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having trouble using a variable in a vue 3 app that has been emitted by a component Mags. The variable works in the importMags function, but I cannot get it read/used by the handleSubmit function. It is always null.

```js
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <Mags name="magResults"  
      @selectedtags="importMags"> </Mags>
      <q-btn label="Submit" type="submit"  />
    </form>
</template>
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "Name",
 components: { Mags },
  setup() {
    function handleSubmit() {
    console.log(nowMags);
    }

    function importMags(selectedMags) {
      let nowMags = selectedMags;
      return nowMags;
    }
    return {
      importMags,
      nowMags: ref(null),
      selectedMags: ref(null),
    
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code snippet.

```html
<form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
```

From this line, we are expecting to call the `handleSubmit()` function, but it is not referenced in the `setup()` function. You have it defined, but you also need to return it.

Next, when you should declare nowMags at the beginning of the setup() function like so:

```js
const nowMags = ref(null)
```

And now in order to read or set the nowMags value in any function, you must call it like `nowMags.value = x` or `x = nowMags.value` or `console.log(nowMags.value)`.

Here's a code snippet that should help piece things together for you.

```js
setup() {
    // Define data variables here
    const nowMags = ref(null)
    const selectedMags = ref(null)
     
    // Define functions here
    const handleSubmit = () => {
      console.log(nowMags.value)
    }
    const importMags(selectedMags) {
      nowMags.value = selectedMags
      return nowMags.value
    }
    
    return {
      nowMags,
      selectedMags,
      importMags,
      handleSubmit
    }
 };
```

Comment: This was really helpful to lay out the basics for me. Thank you! I'm working on learning the composition API. This worked for me, though I left the functions in the function [name] () form. I will need to research the .value structure as I've never seen that before

Answer (score 1):

You declared `nowMags` inside the `importMags()` function. If you want it to be visible outside the function, you need to move the declaration there.

```
 components: { Mags },
  setup() {
    let nowMags; // maybe give it an initial value?

    function handleSubmit() {
    console.log(nowMags);
    }

    function importMags(selectedMags) {
      nowMags = selectedMags;
      return nowMags;
    }
    return {
      importMags,
      nowMags: ref(null),
      selectedMags: ref(null),
    
    };
  },
```

Comment: It's a mistake to reassign ref variables at all. They are supposed to be `const`, only their values need to be reassigned.